# How to manipulate HTML element styles in aurelia-router postRender step

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, aurelia

I would like to make my [Aurelia](http://aurelia.io/) application footer height dynamic, for this I tried to use [aurelia-router](https://github.com/aurelia/router) `postRender` step by following [Aurelia Hub documentation](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/router/latest/router-configuration/8).

Here is the way I tried to achieve it, this is my `app.js` code:

```
export class App {
  configureRouter(config, router) {
    config.title = 'Aurelia';
    var step = {
      run: (navigationInstruction, next) => {
        $('.page-host').css('padding-bottom', $('#footer').outerHeight() + 'px');
        return next();
      }
    };
    config.addPostRenderStep(step);
    config.map([
      { route: ['', 'welcome'], name: 'welcome', moduleId: 'views/welcome', nav: false, title: 'Welcome' }
    ]);

    this.router = router;
  }
}
```

And here is my `app.html` markup:

```
<template>
  <require from="global/nav-bar.html"></require>
  <require from="global/footer-bar.html"></require>
  <require from="styles/style.css"></require>

  <nav-bar></nav-bar>

  <div class="page-host">
    <router-view></router-view>

    <footer-bar></footer-bar>
  </div>
</template>
```

In addition `<footer-bar></footer-bar>` contains the `footer#footer` element.

What am I currently missing?

Comment: why can't you make that dynamic code in attached() life cycle method or navigation success instead of navigation instructions. also better to write in window resize function inside attached